# Google Sheets - Sort alphanumeric Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i'm using Google Sheets and i'm trying to order two columns in descending order, but the order is not correct.

these are the data i want to sort:

[image: these are the data i want to sort]

and i'm using this formula: `=SORT(C4:D, 2, false)`

but Google Sheets returns this:

[image]

i don't know why it puts 10.10 M *(M stands for Millions)* down there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "sort column" using SUBSTITUTE() to remove the text "M" and multiplying by 1 to force the numerals to numbers.

```
=SORT(C4:D,1*SUBSTITUTE(D4:D,"M",""),FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the "M" letter in your second column.
That makes Google Sheet interpreted that column as a string, therefore it applies a string-sorting algorithm.

If you can't change the source column you can create another one with the formula

```
=SPLIT(D4,"M")
```

for every row.

That will remove the "M" letter and you can properly apply the sort function in this new column.